# Deserialize response body with dynamic schema using Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring WebClient to make requests to external API. But there's an endpoint that does not return a uniform json on successful HTTP request. When it has data to return I get a response with following json:

```
{
    "String A": "d7e75c1d-71d1-4628-ad01-cd65a7aabd52",
    "String B": "4a28c303-fb5c-4648-926e-fd2db1178838"
}
```

Howewer when there's nothing it returns an empty json array:

```
[]
```

In both cases HTTP request completes with 200 response code.

Here's my code that does a request:

```java
public Map<String, UUID> getIdsByDisplayNames(List<String> displayNames) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> {
                    uriBuilder.path("/api/display-names/account-ids");
                    for (String displayName : displayNames) {
                        uriBuilder.queryParam("displayName[]", displayName);
                    }
                    return uriBuilder.build();
                })
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, UUID>>() {})
                .block();
    }
```

It works well when there's a json object in response body but when endpoint returns an empty array I get an exception:

> org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.UUID>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

How can I solve it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of asking for a `Map<String, UUID>`, you could ask for a [JsonNode](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).

This class provides some methods `isArray` and `isObject` to determine if the response is a JSON Object or a JSON Array.